# Pssst! (Usage as a verb)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

If you are in a quiet place and someone wants to get your attention by making the '*psst!*' noise, how would you write this?

Does the following work?

> "She heard a soft 'psst!' from somewhere in the basement shadows".

Is there a verb which properly articulates 'psst' without having to write it out?

Comment: Two esses will do it: *Psst!*

Comment: There are reasonable numbers of examples of this and similar expressions on the internet (heard a 'Psst!', heard an 'Ouch!', heard a 'Whoa!', heard a 'Stop!' (note that 'Psst' is a 'soft exclamation').

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that you **NOT** say "He 'psst' in the basement shadows."

Comment: @HotLicks “He psst!ed in the basement shadows” is fine, though.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say whether it fits your particular threshold for "wordness", but ***psst*** has itself seen use as a verb:

> I was just rounding the fourth-floor landing when Claudia **pssted**
>   at me from my mother's door ([Dale Peck *The Garden of Lost and
>   Found*, 2015](https://books.google.com/books?id=KlmTBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT127&dq=Pssted&pg=PT127#v=onepage&q=Pssted&f=false))
>
> “Oh my God.” Someone **pssted** next to Bree, shoving their phone into
>   their neighbour's lap. “Have you SEEN this?" ([Holly Bourne *The
>   Manifesto on How to be Interesting*, 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=5UJfBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT69&dq=Pssted&pg=PT70#v=onepage&q=Pssted&f=false))
>
> This happened to me on more than one occasion, being **“pssted”** at, and
>   all I could do was smile, nod my head, and continue with my novice
>   picking. ([Russell Zanca *Life in a Muslim Uzbek Village: Cotton
>   Farming After Communism CSCA*, 2010](https://books.google.com/books?id=yRoEAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA165&dq=Pssted&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q=Pssted&f=false))
>
> It was not just men **psst, psst-ing** at women. Men **psst, psst-ed** at men.
>   Women **psst, psst-ed** at men. One day an older woman **psst, psst-ed** to
>   ask if I would hold her arm and help her cross the street. ([Lea
>   Aschkenas *Es Cuba: Life and Love on an Illegal Island*, 2006](https://books.google.com/books?id=rDPSE84bDEwC&lpg=PA25&ots=eBz9D2Eu3d&dq=pssting&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=pssting&f=false))

These examples are fairly representative, but not exhaustive. There are also examples from the greater web, including a pssting hashtag.

This does seem to be a relatively recent usage; I didn't find any reliable hits in Google Books for *pssted* or *pssting* before the 21st century. There also doesn't seem to be any standardization of exactly how to write these—in "dubious quotes", hyphenated, or just plain verbed.

With all of these caveats in mind, I think the meaning is quite clear, especially in print, and the usage does seem to have at least a toehold, so if it works in your particular context I think it would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Hiss** is both an appropriate noun and verb:

> Verb
>
> To make a noise like a long s sound:
>   *Why do snakes hiss?
>
>   The iron was hissing and spluttering.
>
>   People in the audience were hissing their disapproval.*
>   ​
>
> To say something in a quiet angry way:
>   *"Shut up, Tom!" she hissed.*
>
> Noun
>
> A sound like the letter *s*:
>   *I heard a hiss and a pop as the cork came out of the bottle.*

([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hiss))

Verb:

> "She heard someone *hiss* at her from somewhere in the basement shadows".

Noun:

> "She heard a *hiss* from someone somewhere in the basement shadows".

Comment: No; 'hiss' could obviously be used hereabouts, but does not "properly articulate 'psst' without having to write it out". 'The snake hissed' rarely means 'the snake tried to get solely my attention'.

Comment: Have to agree with Edwin here. If she heard someone hiss at her, she heard someone make angry noises at her. If she heard a hiss from somewhere in the basement shadows, there’s a good chance she should either call a plumber or unplug her broken radio. Neither sentence can in any reasonable interpretation be read as her hearing someone trying to catch her attention by “psst!”-ing at her.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see what you mean. I would certainly argue that the verb form is appropriate - if someone hisses at you, they are definitely going to catch your attention, on the other hand, if you just hear a *hiss* it  doesn't necessarily mean someone is catching your attention. I'm going to leave my answer up, but with your comments as caveats.

Answer (score 0):

*Psst* is onomatopoetic. It's like saying is there a verb for "ow!" if a person is experiencing pain, or "woof!" is a dog is barking nearby.

You could say "alerted" since *psst* is to alert somebody or get his or her attention.

Comment: But "The dog emitted a 'Woof' " _does_ have a corresponding verb, which you use: _bark_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Woof](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woof) is a verb.

Comment: ...It has two corresponding verbs. Perhaps more. Some corresponding more closely than others. And, @Laurel,  some used so rarely as to be probably better avoided, in an adult register {[GoogleNgrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+dog+barked%2Cthe+dog+woofed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20dog%20barked%3B%2Cc0)}.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, yes, it is grammatically correct.

As far as another way to represent that particular word, the best you'll probably get is an approximation like "a whispered sound." If you describe it in some way as a kind of discrete noise, then, in context, I think people will know what you mean.

Related to another remark here, I *would* describe the way a person would likely *speak* immediately following the interjection as a "hissed" tone, but not the "psst" sound itself.

Also as mentioned, two /s/ are enough.  But you may add more for emphasis, if desired.